# How to create a random Number Genertor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, random, numbers, generator

i wanted to know how i can create a random number generator. But not the usual, i want to build the following:

- In the App there should be a TextField where the user can put in a min and a max value of the
  number generator.
- After clicking a button, there should be a popup or a modified AlertDialog which prints the result

I would be glad if u could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For random number:

```
int MIN;
int MIN;
double randomNumber = random.nextInt(MAX) + MIN;
```

For text fields:
You get the data from text field (For instance using text field onSubmitted) and set it to min and max.

for pop up:
// You can set the title and content
with using the `AlertDialog(title: Text('Random number') , content: Text(randomNumber.toString()))`

For instance this may be the code that you want (just an example, you can change it as you wish):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return new LoginScreenState();
  }
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  int min = 1;
  int max = 1;
  int randomNumber = 1;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter Min'),
            onSubmitted: (thisIsTheMinValueJustSubmitted) {
              min = int.parse(thisIsTheMinValueJustSubmitted);
            },
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter Max'),
            onSubmitted: (thisIsTheMaxValueJustSubmitted) {
              max = int.parse(thisIsTheMaxValueJustSubmitted);
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  randomNumber = Random().nextInt(max - min) + min;
                });
              },
              child: Text('Generate Number')),
          AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Random Number is:'),
            content: Text(randomNumber.toString()),
          ),
          Text(randomNumber.toString()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnak you for your answer. I will try it and respond if it worked for me or not.

Comment: How do i use onSubmitted with the TestField. So how do i set this to min and max? I am pretty new to flutter so i am a bit confused. @Benyamin

Comment: I wrote the whole code for you. just check it.

Comment: if it works then accept the answer to close the topic.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but after trying a bit i discovered, that the numbers are just random and not based on the min and the max. For example i copied you code and ran it. It puts out numbers like it wanrs. When i set a min which  is 20 and a max which is 30 it prints numbers like 31; 49; 38; 2; 6. So it is just random. Please help

Comment: I have fixed and edited the code for you. it turned out the random function should have been rand.nextInt(max - min) + min instead of rand.nextInt(max) + min

Comment: All fine this worked for me! Thank you alot